# Use part of a file for File[Input/Output]Stream

Tags: java, io

I want to add a header to some binary files. My problem is that I want to decode the rest of the file with a third party library that expects a FileInputStream (or Output ofc), without that header ofc. So what I intend to do is read a fixed number of X bytes from a file (trivial), and then have the rest appear transparently as a new Stream - without the header - so that the third party lib can do its thing on it without choking on the header.

How can one go about doing this?

I imagine what works would be to read the rest of the file into a new Filestream in memory, but that seems very inefficient. Is there a better solution?

Thanks.

Comment: Does the API really expect a `FileInputStream` or just an `InputStream`?

Comment: I double checked and you are right, it's a more generic InputStream.

Comment: Can't you just open FileInputStream, read your header part and pass the stream (your stream position will be right after the header) to the library to read the rest of file?

Comment: Why would you need a *new* Stream? Just read the header, and pass the stream to the library method. It will start reading where you stopped.

Comment: Kontantin & JB Nizet: Oh, I didn't know the position was saved. That makes perfect sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to do it. Here is one using a `FileChannel`:

```
public InputStream getInputStream(final Path path)
    throws IOException
{
    final ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(HEADER_SIZE);
    final FileChannel channel = FileChannel.open(path, StandardOpenOption.READ);
    channel.read(buf);
    return Channels.newInputStream(channel);
}
```

You can do the same from a `FileInputStream`.

Note: code above requires Java 7+.